# add css on upper div using jquery

Tags: jquery

i have try to add css on upper div where class is s using jquery.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("span").parents(".s").css({"color": "red", "border": "2px solid red"});
});
```

```css
.ancestors * { 
    display: block;
    border: 2px solid lightgrey;
    color: lightgrey;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body class="ancestors">
  <div style="width:500px;">
    <ul>ul (second ancestor - second grandparent) 
    <ul>ul (first ancestor - first grandparent)
      <li>li (direct parent)
      <div class="s">dummy</div>
        <span>span</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
    </ul>   
  </div>
</body>
```

please help me how to add my css on upper class

Comment: and aslo my example is here [link](https://jsfiddle.net/weL49meL/2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`.prev()`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/)  as the element with class `s` is `span's` sibling not parent.

> Get the immediately preceding sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the previous sibling only if it matches that selector.

```
 $("span").prev(".s")
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("span").prev(".s").css({"color": "red", "border": "2px solid red"});
});
```

```css
.ancestors * { 
    display: block;
    border: 2px solid lightgrey;
    color: lightgrey;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body class="ancestors">
  <div style="width:500px;">
    <ul>ul (second ancestor - second grandparent) 
    <ul>ul (first ancestor - first grandparent)
      <li>li (direct parent)
      <div class="s">dummy</div>
        <span>span</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
    </ul>   
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("span").prev("div.s").css({"color": "red", "border": "2px solid red"});
});
```

```css
.ancestors * { 
    display: block;
    border: 2px solid lightgrey;
    color: lightgrey;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body class="ancestors">
  <div style="width:500px;">
    <ul>ul (second ancestor - second grandparent) 
    <ul>ul (first ancestor - first grandparent)
      <li>li (direct parent)
      <div class="s">dummy</div><!-- not parent but prev element -->
        <span>span</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
    </ul>   
  </div>
</body>
```

Use [.prev()](https://api.jquery.com/prev/)

> Description: Get the immediately preceding sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the previous sibling only if it matches that selector.

You cant use [.parent()](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) because span is not descendant of div

> Description: Get the parent of each element in the current set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("span").siblings(".s").css({
    "color": "red",
    "border": "2px solid red"
  });//if only one sibling with class s is there you can also use sibling()
});
```

```css
.ancestors * { 
    display: block;
    border: 2px solid lightgrey;
    color: lightgrey;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body class="ancestors">
  <div style="width:500px;">
    <ul>ul (second ancestor - second grandparent)
      <ul>ul (first ancestor - first grandparent)
        <li>li (direct parent)
          <div class="s">dummy</div>
          <span>span</span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

[siblings()](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

> Description: Get the siblings of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector

***NOTE:***

You can use `.siblings()` if  only 1 sibling of span has class s

Comment: @SureshSuthar grad to help mate..happy coding

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like `<div class="s">dummy</div>` is actually a parent of your `span` so `.parents(".s")` won't select it. Try `.siblings(".s")` instead.